# WFS display problem using GeoServer and OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, geojson, wfs

I know a lot of issues have already been posted about this tricky situation, but I can't figure out where is the problem in my script and most of the discussions about OpenLayers are outdated.

I'm using OpenLayers 5.2.0 and GeoServer 2.4.0.

I'm trying to retrieve a geojson from a WFS query and display it using OpenLayers, here's my script:

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
    url: 'http://host/geoserver/project/ows?service=WFS&' +
            'version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typename=Project:Countries_110m&' +
            'outputFormat=application/json&srs=EPSG:3857',
    wrapX: false
});

var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource,
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1.0)',
            width: 2
        })
    })
});

try {map.addLayer(vector);}
catch (error) {}
```

I already modified the layer in GeoServer so that it sends the dataset in EPSG:3857 (the source is in EPSG:4326). When I copy/paste the url in Firefox, it returns a clean GeoJSON, but when I try to display it in OpenLayers, it returns:

```
uncaught exception: AssertionError: Assertion failed. See https://openlayers.org/en/5.2.0/doc/errors/#36 for details.
```

The doc indicates a projection issue but the map and the GeoJSON srs are the same, I can't seem to figure out where the problem comes from.

### EDIT

I've tried some other solutions, mainly gathered on [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/297067/openlayers-5-wfs-projection-issue) post, but OpenLayers doesn't display the WFS response:

```
var formatWFS = new ol.format.WFS({});

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    loader: function (extent) {
        $.ajax('http://host/geoserver/project/ows', {
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                service: 'WFS',
                version: '2.0.0',
                request: 'GetFeature',
                typename: 'Project:Countries_110m',
                srsname: 'EPSG:3857',
                bbox: extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857'
            }
        }).done(function (response) {
            vectorSource.addFeatures(formatWFS.readFeatures(response));
        });
        },
    strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
});

vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource,
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#fff2fe',
            width: 1
        })
    })
});

try {map.addLayer(vector);}
catch (error) {}
```

I tried changing the WFS version (with 1.0.0 and 1.1.0) but without luck. With this method, I don't get any javascript error, I have no idea where the problem lies.

Comment: removed GeoServer tag as that seems not to be the problem

Comment: try setting the data (server) and feature (view)  projections in the format `format: new ol.format.GeoJSON({ dataProjection: 'EPSG:3857', featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857' }),`

Comment: What are the previous Q&As that you have reviewed?  If they need updating and/or clarifying then your question could help to improve them.

Comment: @Mike I tried this solution but I get the same error message. Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: @PolyGeo I may have been a bit harsh about those ol questions, I was mainly refering to the over representation of openlayers 2/3 Q&A. I'll edit my question to add some variations of my script I already tried without luck.

Comment: Try feeding clean GeoJSON you get from Firefox to OpenLayers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by upgrading GeoServer to version 2.15.1 as the previous version (2.4.0) was returning by default a GeoJSON with a crs properties that OpenLayers 5 couldn't read :

**OpenLayers 2.4.0 crs property**

```
"crs": {
  "type": "EPSG",
  "properties": {
    "code": "4326"
  }
}
```

**OpenLayers 2.15.1 crs property**

```
"crs": {
  "type": "name",
  "properties": {
    "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326"
  }
}
```

Hence the error #36 OpenLayers was throwing : `Unknown SRS type. Expected "name".`

Comment: [GeoJSON](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7946) no longer has a crs member and uses only one projection `urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC::CRS84` which is not the same as EPSG:4326